# Opening several files with openfiledialog

Tags: javascript, openfiledialog

Im trying to open several files with an openfiledialog and show them in a playlist.
Currently with windowsmediaplayer sdk.

I have this code:

```
function addMediaItem() {
mediaURL = theme.openDialog('FILE_OPEN', 'FILES_ALLMEDIA');

var NewMedia = player.newMedia(mediaURL);
player.currentPlaylist.appendItem(NewMedia);
player.controls.play();
}
```

and is currently only adding 1 item for each click that is done.
What i want is select ex. 2 or 3 media files and show them all at once on the playlist, the code i have seems to only show the first file selected.